# I try to read.csv(comma delimited) with R but some columns have "/" as character(not delimited)

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a .csv file delimited by `,`, but I have a few column names with the character: `/`. When I execute:

```
compt=read.csv("compt.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",dec=".", fill=TRUE,check.names=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the initial characters (`/` ) were replaced by `...` :

Actual results: `Rachel...Papineau`
Expected results: `Rachel / Papineau`

Could you please help me? I would like to see the title of the columns.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try check.names=FALSE

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing `check.names=FALSE` and adding `comment.char=“”` to also turn off the interpretation of comments

```
compt=read.csv(“compt.csv”, header=TRUE, sep=“,”, dec=“.”,fill=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, comment.char=“”,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately, it doesn't work. I need to try other options.